# Change in Fundamental Group by attaching $n$ Cell

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

> Suppose a space $X$ is obtained from a path connected space $Y$ by attaching $n$ cell ($n \geq 3$).Show that $\pi_1(X) \cong \pi_1(Y)$.

I am trying to use the Van Kampen theorem to prove this but i am unable to write it clearly. Could someone give some idea to prove this?

Comment: You're on the right track - the proof of this fact is pretty technical. Have a look at page 50 of https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf for the proof.

Comment: @Zestylemonzi: I think page $50$ talks about $2$ cells.

Comment: Proposition 1.26 part b)? It states that adding an $n$ cell ($n>2$) does not change $\Pi_1$.

Comment: @Zestylemonzi: I see.I was looking in my book which does not have parts!

Comment: SVK says $\pi_1(U_1\cup U_2) = \pi_1(U_1)*_{\pi_1(U_1\cap U_2) }\pi_1(U_2)$, right? So wouldn't you: take $U_1$ to be a neighborhood of your new $n$-cell, take $U_2$ to be a neighborhood of $X$, so that $U_1\cap U_2$ is a neighborhood of the $n-1$-cell you glued to, argue that $U_1$ deformation retracts to an $n$-cell, $U_1\cap U_2$ deformation-retracts to an $n-1$-cell, see that their respective fundamental groups are trivial, then compute the amalgamated free product?

Comment: You can't always find a neighbourhood of the $n$-cell which will deformation retract onto the cell. For instance glue a disk to one of the rings in the Hawaiian earrings. No neighbourhood of the disk is simply connected.

Comment: Does your book have a rigorous description of what "attaching an n-cell" means? For example ar the two spaces identified at a single point?

Comment: @Daron: Not really but i understand it intuitively.

Answer (score 0):

Usually 'attaching' means the cell $C$ intersects $X$ over some well-behaved set, for example the singleton $\{c\}$. We proceed under that assumption.

We have the two inclusion maps $f : \{c\} \to X$ and $g \colon \{c\} \to C$.

We also have three fundamental groups $\pi(X), \pi(C)$ and $\pi(\{c\})$.

**Exercise:** The groups $\pi(C)$ and $\pi(\{c\})$ are particularly simple. What do they look like?

The two maps induce homomorphisms between fundamental groups (with the same names).

$f : \pi(\{c\}) \to \pi(X)$ and $g : \pi(\{c\}) \to \pi(C)$

**Exercise:** What do these homomorphisms look like?

The van Kampen theorem says that once we know what the three groups and two homomorphisms are, we are free to forget about the topology entirely!

All we need to worry about is the mapping diagram $\pi(X) \leftarrow \pi(\{c\}) \to \pi(C)$.

The theorem says $\pi(X \cup C) = \pi(Y)$ is the **pushout** of that diagram. The definition of the pushout is rather long, and computing particular pushouts is often even longer.

**Exercise:** But in this case the groups and homomorphisms (see previous exercises) are straightforward enough that the pushout can only be $\pi(X)$.